# code in android to simulate gps work

Tags: android, json

I'm working on a project that combines Android with a web application. What I want to do is send GPS coordinates from the Android phone to a web application that will display the  location,please help me in coding,because am not good in android coding

Comment: Perhaps you should keep practicing at it then.  You will get better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Location Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)  for this

```
   private LocationManager locationManager;
    public LocationListener locationListener;
    public LocationListener locationListener2;

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                locationListener2 = new MyLocationListener();               
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener2);



    //Location lister
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            mlongti = loc.getLongitude();
            mlatiti = loc.getLatitude();
            GeoPoint userLoc = new GeoPoint((int) (mlatiti * 1E6), (int) (mlongti * 1E6));
            LItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new LItemizedOverlay(selfImage,getParent(), "",userLoc,display);

            try {           
                OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(userLoc, "", "");
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
            MapController mc = map.getController();         
            mc.animateTo(userLoc);
            mc.setZoom(10);
            map.invalidate();       
            if(locationManager!=null && locationListener2 != null){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener2);
                locationManager= null;
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

See [Android Location API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#locationapi_run) also

Answer (score 0):

Please use code for get latitude and longitude

public class MyLocationListener extends Service implements LocationListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyLocationListener";

private Context context = null;

private Location location = null;
private LocationManager locationManager = null;

public static boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

public double latitude = 0.0;
public double longitude = 0.0;
public String location_address=null;


// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

public MyLocationListener(Context ctx) {
    Log.v(TAG+".MyLocationListener", "MyLocationListener constructor called");
    this.context = ctx;
    getLocationValue();
}

public Location getLocationValue() {
    Log.v(TAG+".getLocationValue", "getLocationValue method called");

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if(isGPSEnabled){

            this.canGetLocation = true;
            Log.v(TAG+".getLocationValue", "GPS provider enabled");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Gps", 1).show();
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);                     
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();                              
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();                                
                        Log.v(TAG,"Gps Co-ordinates are:" + latitude+ " " + longitude);
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Co-ordinates are: " + latitude + " "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //GetAddressFromCoordinates(location);
                        //setLocationDataToBean();
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        else if(isNetworkEnabled){

            //Toast.makeText(context, "Net", 1).show();
            Log.v(TAG+".getLocationValue", "Network provider enabled");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);                 

            if (locationManager != null)
            {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.v(TAG,"Co-ordinates are: " + latitude + " "+ longitude);
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Network Provider Co-ordinates are: " + latitude + " "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //GetAddressFromCoordinates(location);
                    //setLocationDataToBean();
                }
            }           
        }
        else{
            showSettingsAlert();
        }           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}



/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocationListener.this);
    }
}   
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }   
    return latitude;
}   
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }   
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
```

Now in second part send this lat and long to server use asynctask

private class GetResult extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.v(TAG + ".doInBackground", "doInBackground method call");
        String response1 = null;

    /*  for (String url : urls) {
            WebHelper webHelper = new WebHelper();
            response = webHelper.getResult(url);
            Log.v(TAG+".doInBackground", "json response is:" + response);
        }*/

           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost  httppost = new HttpPost("use web url");
          //  Log.d("response", "WORKING");
            try {


                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long",long));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                WebHelper webHelper = new WebHelper();
                response1 = webHelper.convertStreamToString(is);
                Log.v(TAG+".doInBackground", "json response is:" + response1);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response1;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.v(TAG + ".onPostExecute", "onPostExecute method call");
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.v(TAG+".onPostExecute", "json response is:" + result);

        /*
            if(msg != null){
                // check status here for response


    }
```